# Thumbnails for PDFs in a document libary

Tags: 2013, pdf

How can I create a view with thumbnails of stored pdf documents in a document libary on sharepoint on-premise 2013?

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111758/create-a-document-library-thumbnails-view otherwise you can try it with search results or content search web part and an display template.